# PgAdminIII - How to create a database and tables in one single script

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to run the following script that creates a DB and a table at the same time. Because I'm using PgAdminIII, I have to use the Query Tool of an already existing database. I think that might be causing the problem. So this is how my script goes:

```
 CREATE DATABASE homework;

 CREATE TABLE exampletable (
    id int NOT NULL,
    description text,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
 );
```

BUT, I get this error:
ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string
********** Error **********

ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string
SQL state: 25001

Any help is appreciated! Love y'all!

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this like that? You cannot do cross database references, you will get error like that: `ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "test1.public.exampletable"` so even if you would create database in multi-command string then you still wouldn't be able to create anything inside it, unless you use something like dblink.

Answer (score 0):

This is because PgAdmin3 wraps your query in BEGIN...END transaction blocks.   If you did the same thing within psql, you could do this:

```
CREATE DATABASE homework;

\c homework;

CREATE TABLE exampletable (
id int NOT NULL,
description text,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Since psql would execute these statements in auto-commit mode, they would each be executed individually in a transaction, and would create the table as you expect.

Comment: Isn't psql the same thing as pgadmin? where do I download psql from?

Answer (score 0):

Select & Execute each CREATE sql at a time in query tool.